# Prevent "0" in CountDistinct in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following expression:

```
=CountDistinct(IIf((Fields!txtGrade.Value = "*") 
And (Fields!txtCurrentSubjectName.Value = "3D Design"), 
Fields!intGradeTransposeValue.Value, Nothing))
```

There are 5 different `txtGrade.Value` in all - `*, 1, 2, 3, 4` not every subject will have a grade. In the columns that have no values the expression is returning back a `0` - is there anyway I can just get it to show a blank cell with no number in it at all. This is what it currently outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can use here.  First, you could simply wrap the entire expression in an `IIF` that replaces the zeros with nothing.

```
=IIF(CountDistinct(IIf((Fields!txtGrade.Value = "*") 
And (Fields!txtCurrentSubjectName.Value = "3D Design"), 
Fields!intGradeTransposeValue.Value, Nothing)) = 0, "", 
(CountDistinct(IIf((Fields!txtGrade.Value = "*") 
And (Fields!txtCurrentSubjectName.Value = "3D Design"), 
Fields!intGradeTransposeValue.Value, Nothing))))
```

The second option would be to set the text box properties to show zeros as a blank as shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I tried using the expression, but on running it is saying it is expecting an additional ) . I have tried to remedy this but to no avail. Do you have any idea where the closing parenthesis should go - I have tried in almost every place I can think of

Comment: That's strange because I was able to copy that expression from my answer, sub in some fields from my dataset and it runs just fine.  Basically all I did was the IIF that checks if the `CountDistinct` is equal to zero, setting that to "", otherwise returning the result of the count.  I also nested the second declaration of the `CountDistinct` in a set of parenthesis so your original expression ends in two, but the new expression should end with four.

Comment: I know, I can't figure it out either. I have used your other suggestion though and this is working beautifully, so I will accept the answer based on this. Thank you again